# how to process file from a java process uploaded using servlets

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I've developed a Java servlet (tomcat 6.0) that handles file upload to server from client. Thus far, all my javaapp can do right now is upload a file. I've coded another java application which scans the file (excel document, apachi POI), and parse specific information from it, then prints out the info.

The goal is basically to use the uploaded file, then call the java program to process the file. Then spit out the data from java console (the results) to the HTML page.

Here's my code for the servlet. I followed [this](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/eclipse-file-upload-servlet-with-apache-common-file-upload) tutorial to make this.

Servlet:

```
package net.codejava.upload;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

/**
 * A Java servlet that handles file upload from client.
 * @author www.codejava.net
 */
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "upload";
    private static final int THRESHOLD_SIZE     = 1024 * 1024 * 3;  // 3MB
    private static final int MAX_FILE_SIZE      = 1024 * 1024 * 40; // 40MB
    private static final int MAX_REQUEST_SIZE   = 1024 * 1024 * 50; // 50MB

    /**
     * handles file upload via HTTP POST method
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // checks if the request actually contains upload file
        if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            writer.println("Request does not contain upload data");
            writer.flush();
            return;
        }

        // configures upload settings
        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        factory.setSizeThreshold(THRESHOLD_SIZE);
        factory.setRepository(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));

        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        upload.setFileSizeMax(MAX_FILE_SIZE);
        upload.setSizeMax(MAX_REQUEST_SIZE);

        // constructs the directory path to store upload file
        String uploadPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("")
            + File.separator + UPLOAD_DIRECTORY;
        // creates the directory if it does not exist
        File uploadDir = new File(uploadPath);
        if (!uploadDir.exists()) {
            uploadDir.mkdir();
        }

        try {
            // parses the request's content to extract file data
            List formItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator iter = formItems.iterator();

            // iterates over form's fields
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
                // processes only fields that are not form fields
                if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    String fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                    String filePath = uploadPath + File.separator + fileName;
                    File storeFile = new File(filePath);

                    // saves the file on disk
                    item.write(storeFile);
                }
            }
            request.setAttribute("message", "Upload has been done successfully!");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            request.setAttribute("message", "There was an error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/message.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Web XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>UploadServletApp</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>UploadServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>net.codejava.upload.UploadServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/UploadServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My upload JSP page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <form method="post" action="UploadServlet" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Select file to upload: <input type="file" name="uploadFile" />
            <br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </form>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

My message jsp page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h2>${requestScope.message}</h2>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone please walk me through on what to do now, on how to call the separate java program I made (code not posted here) to process the file, then get it to spit out the data from java console (the results) to the 'message' HTML jsp page? I've looked everywhere and cannot found out how to resolve this issue. It's driving me crazy.

Comment: What means have you for communicating with this other java program?  What does it do? Can you run it off the command line to process this file?

Comment: So basically the other program I wrote is really just one class of code. It can read an excel document and parse information from it, and prints it out. This program which I posted here is basically a web app. What I'm trying to do is be able to upload the document online, run it in my java program that parses the information, then print the results on the html page I've created. I really don't understand how to take the uploaded document from the server and then send it to my java program to run it. Also, I'm very much a noob at java. I'm still very new to this language.

Comment: instead of storing file at temporary location,store it at particular location and then get file from that physical location to process.

Comment: Well the problem  @SanjayPatel is that I don't even know how to begin looking for the file. After the user hits the submit button and uploads the file...Then what? I don't even know how to continue the code. I'm just so lost.

Comment: your other program process the file after uploading to server?

Comment: That's what I want it to do. Right now, my other program only knows that the document is in my workspace, and parses it that way. It then, spits the results out in the java console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create one method which returns String and takes String as argument.

```
public String getContent(String filePath) {
    // logic goes here
}
```

You already created one class for that inside you need to create this method.
Then you need to change some parts of servlet:

Declare a variable `String fileName = "";` in `doPost` method and change

```
if (!item.isFormField()) {
    String fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName();
```

to

```
if (!item.isFormField()) {
    fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName(); // remove String
```

Call your class after while loop (Let say `FilterData` is your class name)

```
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    // Code
}
FilterData fd = new FilterData();
String data = fd.getData(uploadPath + "//" + fileName);
request.setAttribute("message", data);
```

And remove

```
request.setAttribute("message", "Upload has been done successfully!");
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote the other java code, just include the class in your project: instantiate the class and pass it the file.  Here in your servlet where you write the file to disk

```
  // saves the file on disk
  item.write(storeFile);
```

You can instantiate your class and pass it the File object, or the path of the file.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but I'm still lost on how to really begin this. Like I commented above, how will this possibly work once the user submits the document and uploads it? I really just don't know how to begin this part of the code.